# Setup a VPS as a streaming replicator (for an online radio)?

Tags: linux, streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have a real radio station, and we stream the radio over the internet through our website. However the radio has been growing and our internet link can't support the amount of players anymore.

My idea was to get a VPS, then stream the radio from our office to the VPS, and then have the VPS stream to the listeners on our website.

Could someone suggest me a way to do that?
I know it is possible, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I take it that you've implemented multicast for this? If not you need to: it will cut your bandwidth requirement dramatically.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. I haven't implemented multicast, and I don't know how I could implement it. The main problem is that we're localized in a more distant area so we can only have DSL internet over Comcast (10Mbps) in our location. Even if we implement multicast, would it help us in the long term, knowing that we are limited to a max of 10Mbps only? I think that if we could stream to one VPS with an 100Mbps link for example, consumed bandwidth wouldn't matter that much. Our main problem is just throughput, as our pipe ins't large enough.

Comment: This is off topic for a software development site, but since you're here: unicast (the default) allocates an audio stream to each listener. Ten listeners require roughly ten times as much bandwidth as one. Multicast allows your listeners to subscribe to a single audio stream. The actual replication is handled by switches and routers downstream, so you only have one audio stream to worry about. I can't help with implementation. Your VPS replicator will offload your DSL, but your ISP will probably charge for bandwidth. You might solve a capacity problem but your costs will likely rise.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy, and is the normal way to get it done.  Set up a [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/broadcast-tools) or [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/download.php) server on this VPS, and have it either relay your existing stream on your DSL connection, or connect your encoder directly to SHOUTcast/Icecast on the VPS.

Alternatively, look for SHOUTcast/Icecast hosting if you aren't comfortable setting this up yourself.  I'm doing some free experimental hosting for small stations at the moment.  E-mail preview@audiopump.co if you're interested.